# how ca I fix this error after exacting npx cap add android?

Tags: node.js, npm, ionic-framework

After running "npm install @capacitor/android" I did "npx cap add android" but it gives me the following error:

```
npm ERR! could not determine executable to run
```

Node version: v20.10.0 and my npm version: 10.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, that error occurs when the dependency (in this case capacitor) is not installed. Did you run `npm install`?

Comment: It says the following in the package.json file:

  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/android": "^5.6.0"
@Yochyo